# How to create a nested ListBuffer within another ListBuffer n times in Scala?

Tags: scala, list, append, listbuffer

I have an empty`ListBuffer[ListBuffer[(String, Int)]]()` initialized like so, and given a number `n`, I want to fill it with `n` `ListBuffer[(String, Int)]`.

For example, if `n=2` then I can initialize two `ListBuffer[(String, Int)]` within `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[(String, Int)]]()` if that makes any sense. I was trying to loop `n` times and use the insertAll function to insert an empty list but I didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## use fill

`fill` is a standard Scala library function in order to fill a data structure with predefined elements. Its quite handy and save lot of typing.

```
ListBuffer.fill(100)(ListBuffer("Scala" -> 1))
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.mutable._

scala> ListBuffer.fill(100)(ListBuffer("Scala" -> 1))
res4: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(String, Int)]] = ListBuffer(ListBuffer((Scala,1)), ListBuffer((Scala,1)), ListBuffer((Scala,1)), ListBuffer((Scala,1)), ListBuffer((Scala,1)) ...
```

**fill implementation in Standard library**

```
def fill[A](n: Int)(elem: => A): CC[A] = {
    val b = newBuilder[A]
    b.sizeHint(n)
    var i = 0
    while (i < n) {
      b += elem
      i += 1
    }
    b.result()
  }
```

The above implementation is for one dimensional data structure.

## General suggestions

Looks like you are using Scala like the Java way. This is not good. Embrace functional way for doing things for obvious benefits.

Use `immutable` collections like `List`, `Vector` instead of `mutable` collections. Do not use mutable collections until and unless you have string reason for it.

Same thing can be done using immutable List

```
List.fill(100)(List("scala" -> 1))
```

`scala -> 1` is same as `("scala", 1)`